# How to convert an IGroupedObservable to IGrouping?

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive, rx.net

I have an observable sequence of elements that have a `char Key` property, that has values in the range from `'A'` to `'E'`. I want to group these elements based on this key. After grouping them I want the result to by an observable of groups, so that I can process each group separately. My problem is that I can't find a nice way to preserve the key of each group in the final observable. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
var observable = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    .Take(42)
    .GroupBy(n => (char)(65 + n % 5))
    .Select(grouped => grouped.ToArray())
    .Merge();

observable.Subscribe(group =>
    Console.WriteLine($"Group: {String.Join(", ", group)}"));
```

Output:

```
Group: 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40
Group: 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41
Group: 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37
Group: 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38
Group: 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39
```

The groups are correct, but the keys (`'A'` - `'E'`) are lost. The type of the `observable` is `IObservable<long[]>`. What I would like it to
be instead, is an `IObservable<IGrouping<char, long>>`. This way the `group.Key` would be available inside the final subscription code. But as far as I can see
there is no built-in way to convert an [`IGroupedObservable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229876(v=vs.103)) (the result of the [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229301(v=vs.103)) operator) to an [`IGrouping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2). I can see the operators `ToArray`,
`ToList`, `ToLookup`, `ToDictionary` etc, but not a `ToGrouping` operator. My question is, how can I implement this operator?

Here is my incomplete attempt to implement it:

```
public static IObservable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> ToGrouping<TKey, TSource>(
    this IGroupedObservable<TKey, TSource> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>(observer =>
    {
        // What to do?
        return source.Subscribe();
    });
}
```

My intention is to use it in the original example instead of the `ToArray`, like this:

```
.Select(grouped => grouped.ToGrouping())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does most of what you want:

```
var observable = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    .Take(42)
    .GroupBy(n => (char)(65 + n % 5))
    .SelectMany(grouped => grouped.ToArray().Select(a => (key: grouped.Key, results: a)));
```

That's an `IObservable<ValueTuple<TKey, TResult[]>`. If you wanted the `IGrouping` interface, you would have to make an object, since I don't think there's one available for you:

```
public static class Grouping
{
    // Because I'm too lazy to code types
    public static Grouping<TKey, TResult> Create<TKey, TResult>(TKey key, IEnumerable<TResult> results)
    {
        return new Grouping<TKey, TResult>(key, results);
    }
}

public class Grouping<TKey, TResult> : IGrouping<TKey, TResult>
{
    public Grouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TResult> results)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Results = results;
    }
    
    public TKey Key { get; }
    public IEnumerable<TResult> Results { get; }

    public IEnumerator<TResult> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Results.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Results.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

then your observable becomes:

```
var o2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    .Take(42)
    .GroupBy(n => (char)(65 + n % 5))
    .SelectMany(grouped => grouped.ToArray().Select(a => Grouping.Create(grouped.Key, a)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you want:

```
IObservable<(char Key, long[] Values)> observable =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
        .Take(42)
        .GroupBy(n => (char)(65 + n % 5))
        .Select(grouped => new { Key = grouped.Key, Values = grouped.ToArray() })
        .SelectMany(x => x.Values, (k, v) => (Key: k.Key, Values: v));

observable.Subscribe(group =>
    Console.WriteLine($"Group {group.Key}: {String.Join(", ", group.Values)}"));
```

I get:

```
Group A: 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40
Group B: 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41
Group C: 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37
Group D: 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38
Group E: 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39
```

Comment: Yeap, that does the job. But having to work with a generic `ValueTuple<TKey, TSource[]` is less satisfying than working with the semantically meaningful `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>`! 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - OK... (insert confused emoji here).

Comment: To be honest I didn't ask this question because I had a real problem to solve. I asked it because solving this hypothetical problem in a nice way (the way asked in the title) was a bit challenging. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Fair enough, I didn't read the title too clearly. It should be an easy fix though.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to implement the `ToGrouping` operator without creating a custom class that implements the `IGrouping` interface. It is more succinct but less efficient than Shlomo's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65025007/11178549).

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an observable sequence containing a single 'IGrouping' that has the same
/// key with the source 'IGroupedObservable', and contains all of its elements.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> ToGrouping<TKey, TSource>(
    this IGroupedObservable<TKey, TSource> source)
{
    return source
        .ToList()
        .Select(list => list.GroupBy(_ => source.Key).Single());
}
```

This implementation assumes that the `TKey` type does not implement the `IEquatable` interface in some crazy way, that returns different hashcodes for the same value, or considers a value not equal to itself. In case that happens, the [`Single`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single) LINQ operator will throw an exception.

Comment: I actually deliberately didn’t do this. `IObservable<IGrouping<TKey, TResult>>` implicitly implies that you’ll get each grouping once it is ready/complete. This solution gives all groupings only when they’re all ready.

Comment: @Shlomo I am not sure I understand. The return value of this answer's `ToGrouping` operator is an observable that emits a single `IGrouping`. It is emitted when the source `IGroupedObservable` completes. Could you elaborate about the differences between the two solutions?